# Flaskr - I cannot turn off/clear caching in the unittest

Tags: python, flask

I have been extending the flaskr tutorial by adding some more funky html, however when I run the unittest, it still returns old html.
   https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/

I have tried turning off caching in the html (for debugging) and I have tried configuring the app in the **init** file and conftest file.

Within the base.html template, the following has been added:

```
<!--prevent cache - makes debugging easier, but slower -->
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Within the create_app function of the **init**.py file I have added the following:

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "null"
```

Within the conftest.py file of the unit tests, I have added the following:

```
# Turn off caching
app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "null"
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
```

When I print the response from the test_index function, I am expecting an entirely new set of html that includes body etc.   Instead I am getting the old flaskr html, which is along the lines:

```
def test_index(client, auth):
    print("\n\n********test_index************\n\n")
    response = client.get('/')
    print(response.data)



<!doctype html>
  <title>Posts - Flaskr</title>
  ...
  </section>
```

Comment: is it correct that both of your config files have the same values for `CACHE_TYPE` and `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT`?

Comment: I am a bit new to Flask and these are solutions that I have found on the internet and have copied them in.   I just want to make sure nothing is cached so that the unittest works.   I don't know if there are any negative consequences of setting both of these.   I would really appreciate some help on what to do to completely turn of and clear caching in flaskr.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to this.

I basically cleared out lots of directories such as **pycache** and the virtual environment directory.   I then recreated the virtual environment from an old version of the requirements.txt file and added any extra packages to this environment that were not in this original file.   I also had to install the package itself using pip install -e .

Everything seems to work now.